# ruby - get name of class from class method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am trying to get the name of the class from within a static method within the class:

```
class A
  def self.get_class_name
    self.class.name.underscore.capitalize.constantize
  end
end
```

Though this returns Class instead of A. Any thoughts on how do I get A instead?

Eventually I also want to have a class B that inherits from A that will use the same method and will return B when called.

The reason I am doing this is because I have another object under this domain eventually: `A::SomeOtherClass` which I want to use using the result I receive.

Comment: Is the method supposed to return a string, i.e. `"A"`?

Comment: @Stefan, I think he was just trying to understand how to get the current class name inside a class method. This is probably just an example.

Comment: Do you want the class `A` or the name (string) `"A"`?

Comment: What is constantize in Ruby?

Comment: Hey everyone, essentially I want to return the class object so I can use it somewhere else. But the string works as well :)

Comment: @DanBenjamin from within class methods, `self` returns the class object and `name` returns the class name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove `.class`:

```
class A
  def self.get_class_name
    self.name.underscore.capitalize.constantize
  end
end
```

`self` in a context of a class (rather than the context of an instance method) refers to the class itself.

This is why you write `def self.get_class_name` to define a class method. This means add method `get_class_name` to `self` (aka `A`). It is equivalent to `def A.get_class_method`.

It is also why when you tried `self.class.name` you got `Class` - the `Object#class` of `A` is `Class`.

To make this clearer, consider the output of:

```
class A
  puts "Outside: #{self}"

  def self.some_class_method
    puts "Inside class method: #{self}"
  end

  def some_instance_method
    puts "Inside instance method: #{self}"
  end
end

A.some_class_method
A.new.some_instance_method
```

Which is:

```
Outside: A
Inside class method: A
Inside instance method: #<A:0x218c8b0>
```

Answer (score 0):

The output for this:

```
class NiceClass
  def self.my_class_method
    puts "This is my #{name}"
  end
end

NiceClass.my_class_method
```

Will be:

```
This is my NiceClass
```